# Python: Count how many times a word occurs in a file

Tags: python, file, count

I have a file that contains a city name and then a state name per line in the file. I am suppose to count how many times a state name occurs and return the value.

for example, if my file contained:

```
Los Angeles   California
San Diego     California
San Francisco California
Albany        New York
Buffalo       New York
Orlando       Florida
```

I am suppose to return how many times each state name occurs. I have this for California.

```
for line in f:
    California_count=line.find("California")
    if California_count!=-1:
        total=line.count("California")
print(total)
```

This only gives me the value 1, which I am assuming is because it occurs 1 time per line. How do I get it to return the number 3 instead of the number 1?

Comment: You're overwriting the value of `total` every time. Try using `+=` (add to and assign). BTW, this is what [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) does really well if you are interested.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer).  That does two things.  It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.  See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
total = 0

with open('input.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        found = line.find('California')
        if found != -1 and found != 0:
            total += 1

print total
```

output:

```
3
```

Comment: I think this is not correct for a line that contains New York on both columns.

Answer (score 7):

Use dictionary for storing counters:

```
data = """Los Angeles   California
San Diego     California
San Francisco California
Albany        New York
Buffalo       New York
Orlando       Florida""".splitlines()

counters = {}
for line in data:
    city, state = line[:14], line[14:]
    # city, state = line.split('\t') # if separated by tabulator
    if state not in counters:
        counters[state] = 1
    else:
        counters[state] += 1
print counters
# {'Florida': 1, 'New York': 2, 'California': 3}
```

You can simplify it by using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
counter = defaultdict(int)
for line in data:
    city, state = line[:14], line[14:]
    counter[state] += 1

print counter
# defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'Florida': 1, 'New York': 2, 'California': 3})
```

or using `collections.Counter` and generator expression:

```
from collections import Counter
states = Counter(line[14:] for line in data)
# Counter({'California': 3, 'New York': 2, 'Florida': 1})
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could just use the `re` module, and regex it:

```
import re

states = """
Los Angeles   California
San Diego     California
San Francisco California
Albany        New York
Buffalo       New York
Orlando       Florida
"""

found = re.findall('[cC]alifornia', states)

total = 0

for i in found:
    total += 1

print total
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted Answer for this common problem I believe covers what 'bw61293' asked for because of the format of his Text File, but is not a general solution for all Text Files!

He asked for 'Count how many times a word occurs in a file', the accepted answer can only count the word 'California' once per line. So if the word appears twice on a line then it will only count it once. Although this does work for the given format, it is not a general solution to say if the 'file' was a book.

A fix to the Accepted answer would be below, of using nltk to break the line into a list of words. The only problem is make sure to pip install the nltk library with '`pip install nltk`' in Command Prompt, beware its a big library. If you want to use Anaconda use '`conda install -c anaconda nltk`'. I used the Tweet Tokenizer because apostrophes in words like "`don't`" will split the string into a list `['don', "'t"]` but the TweetTokenizer will return `["don't"]`, among other reasons. I also made it case insensitive by just using `.lower()` in `.count()`. I hope this will help people who want a more general solution to the question of 'Count how many times a word occurs in a file'.

I am new to StackOverflow so please give feedback to improvements to my code or to what I have written for my first comment ever!

**UPDATE I MADE AN ERROR, below is now fixed!! (Keep in mind this is a case insensitive search, if you want it case sensitive please remove the .lower() from the list comprehension. Thanks.) I also promise to make an answer without using nltk when I get enough time.**

```
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer
tknzr = TweetTokenizer()

total = 0

with open('input.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        LineList = tknzr.tokenize(line)
        LineLower = [x.lower() for x in LineList]
        found = LineLower.count('california')
        if found != -1 and found != 0:
            total += found

print(total)
```

Comment: I think it's great that you mentioned why the accepted answer should be improved, however, your answer is a bit overkill in my opinion. You mentioned it yourself NLTK is a huge library...

Check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22849797/12403182) , provided by @m.wasowski , on how to solve this problem in a simpler fashion.

Comment: Fair point @AMerii your right it is overkill. I will post an update and add some code with a library that isn't as resource intensive.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the spaces in your post are meant to be tabs, the following code will give you a dict containing the counts for all of the states in the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

counts = {}
with open('states.txt', 'r') as statefile:
    for i in statefile:
        state = i.split('\t')[1].rstrip()
        if state not in counts:
            counts[state] = 0
        else:
            counts[state] += 1
    print(counts)
```

Comment: I think your code gives the wrong final count - returns a zero for a single instance.
changing 
`count[state] = 0`
to 
`count[state] = 1` 
will* correct this. 
* I havn't tested this, but I'm pretty sure this correction is right.