# Counting how many times a number appears in a file

Tags: python, file, dictionary, count

So I'm taking a file and running it through my code. Example of what appears on file per line:

```
100
200
300
100
200
400
```

My goal is to get my code to iterate through the numbers in the file and the output is a dictionary with the number as the key and how ever many times it appears in the file as the value. For example:

{100:2,200:2,300:1,400:1}

This is what I've put together so far.

```
def counts(filename):
    d={}
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f
            for number in line:


    return d
```

Also,would I be able to use .count() for this? So could I create a list of numbers in the file and set those as the keys and then have a list for the set the corresponding amount of times each number appears and set that as the values to the keys?

Comment: [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

Comment: If there is only 1 number per line, why do you need the inner loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Count how many times a word occurs in a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22849662/python-count-how-many-times-a-word-occurs-in-a-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def counts(filename):
    d={}
    with open(filename) as f:
        contents = f.read()

    contents = contents.split("\n")
    del contents[-1]
    contents =  map(int, contents)

    for content in contents:
        if content not in d:
            d[content] = 1
        else:
            d[content] = d[content] + 1

    return d


print counts(filename)
```

o/p

```
{200: 2, 300: 1, 400: 1, 100: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can create a matrix where each position could represent a number and its content represent the number it appears in the file.
furthermore, u can create a comparator that compares with the numbers from the file and then increase the counter

Answer (score 0):

For each number in the file, if it does not appear as a key in your dictionary, add it (with a count of 0); regardless, increment the count for that number.

Comment: OP seems to know the logic, and to need help with coding.

Comment: Agree with the latter; not at all clear about the former.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a generator to read all of the lines and converts them to integers.

```
from collections import Counter
from csv import reader

def counts(filename):
    return Counter(int(line[0]) for line in reader(open(filename)) if line)


c = counts('my_file.csv')
>>> c
Counter({'100': 2, '200': 2, '300': 1, '400': 1})

>>> c.most_commont(5)
[('200', 2), ('100', 2), ('300', 1), ('400', 1)]

>>> dict(c)
{'100': 2, '200': 2, '300': 1, '400': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which is easily convertible to a `dict` once the counting is done.

```py
from collections import Counter 

def counts(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return dict(Counter(int(line) for line in f))

# {200: 2, 100: 2, 300: 1, 400: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `defaultdict` to keep track of your number counts:

```
from collections import defaultdict
frequencies = defaultdict(int)
for number in open('numbers.txt'):
    frequencies[int(number)] += 1

for number in sorted(frequencies.keys()):
    print(number, ':', frequencies[number])
```

Gives:

```
100 : 2
200 : 2
300 : 1
400 : 1
```

With a regular dictionary, you need to catch the `KeyError` on the first time the number is encountered:

```
count = {}
for number in open('numbers.txt'):
    try:
        count[int(number)] += 1
    except KeyError:
        count[int(number)] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only simple python:

```
word_count = {}
with open('temp.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        word_count[line[:-1]] = word_count.setdefault(line[:-1], 0) + 1
```

If you wish to use fancy libraries, you can go with @alexander's answer with `Counter`.